# VLC to use native notification

Tags: vlc, notification

I want to enable my desktop notification(notify-osd) of VLC.. look the pic below.

How to?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok i found it:

- run VLC and go to `VLC-->Tools-->Preferences`
- check the `All` field
- click on `Control interface`
- check `LibNotify Notification Plugin`

[image]